# KDB: How to make convert a table column into a list?

Tags: kdb

if I have a list and table:

```
a:("12";"34";"56")

bb:([]c:("90";"12";"65"))
```

And I do this:

```
a except (select c from bb)
```

I get the following error:

```
length
[5]  (.q.except)

[4]  a except (select c from bb)
```

Perhaps (select c from bb) is still a table? How do I convert a column to a list so that the except statement works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` does indeed output a table. If you want the output to be a list then use `exec`:

```
q)a except exec c from bb
"34"
"56"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using "exec", which will return the column as the list.

```
a except exec c from bb
```

or

```
a except bb`c
```

Answer (score 1):

Both perfectly good answers, but personally I prefer t[`col]

```
a:("12";"34";"56");
bb:([]c:("90";"12";"65"));
a except bb[`c]
```

It also works better if calling dynamically

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
q)a:("12";"34";"56")
q)bb:([]c:("90";"12";"65"))
q)([]c:a) except bb
c
----
"34"
"56"
```